# How to make onChange text in ReactJS responsive

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am building an input form where visitors will immediately see what they are typing, but when I try to resize the screen width and you have typed a lot of text, there will be a scrollbar X show up when the screen width is small. In other words how can I make that responsive?

```js
import React from "react";

export default class Form extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
   data: null,
   header: "Please enter something in this input field and see what happens :)"
  }

  this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
 
 };

 updateState(e) {
  this.setState({data: e.target.value});
 }

   render() {

    var myStyle = {
     padding: 30,
     color: "black",
     display: "block",
     backgroundColor: "#e2f7fd",
     marginTop: 10

    }

      return (
         <div style= {myStyle}>
          <h1>{this.state.header}</h1>
            <input type = "text" value = {this.state.data} 
               onChange = {this.updateState} />
            <h4>{this.state.data}</h4>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `word-wrap: break-word` to your `<h4>` tag. This will break the word to the newline if it exceeds the viewport.

```css
h4{
  word-wrap: break-word;
  }
```

```html
<h4>ajhsvdjahvsdjahvsdjahvsdjahvsjdhavdjhavsdjvahjdhvajdvajdvajsvdjahsvdjahvsdjahvsdjhavsdjhavsjdhavsjdhvasjdhvajshdvajshvdjashvdjahsvdjhasvjdhasvdjahsvdjahvsdjahvsjahsvdjahvdjhasvd</h4>

<!-- In React it will be <h4 style={{wordWrap: 'break-word'>}}></h4> -->
```

Try removing the `word-wrap`, you will see the y-axis scrollbar